# Почему вызов отрисовки (draw call) дорогой?

Tags: оптимизация, производительность, graphics, render, gpu

Существует куча способов оптимизации кол-ва вызовов отрисовки. К примеру это может быть батчинг или текстурный атлас. Отдать всё возможное на гпу за раз гораздо выгоднее, чем отправлять кусочками. Но почему? Разве конечный объём требуемой работы от этого изменится?

Comment: В 2 словах - проц отдаёт медленнее чем видюха рисует, поэтому чем меньше раз отдавать тем быстрее отрисует в конечном итоге.

Answer (score 2):

По сути вы грузите вертексные буферы текстуры и прочее на видеокарту. Потом делаете вызов отрисовки. Причем чем их меньше, тем быстрее все это дело работает.

Почему? Все просто. Если раньше (взять legacy OpenGL glBegin...) было нормально отправлять все по шине каждый кадр, то теперь все хранится на видеокарте и нагрузку на шину стараются максимально сократить, просто потому что теперь видеокарты и процессоры гораздо быстрее считают, чем летят данные по шине между ними. А как известно, пока данные по шине летят, процессор вынужден практически простаивать из-за скорости шины, и видеокарта простаивает тоже, пока не получит данные.

Аналогию можно провести с трубами и емкостями. Емкость увеличилась, а вот труба осталась прежней.

Кстати, на встраиваемых платформах и игровых приставках cpu и gpu делят одну и ту же память, так что в таком случае можно не сильно париться по поводу drawcall'ов